# Como pasar los parametros de c# a una plantilla HTML y genera PDF

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

de antemano gracias por ayudarme, ¿como podría pasar  parámetros a unas variables que tengo asignadas en una plantilla .HTM estoy intentando generar un documento PDF y que al final los valores que mando llamar desde: Ejemplo **FechaCalculo** sean remplazados en la varaible **{@FechaCalculo@}** de mi plantilla, estoy usando IronPDF para convertir el template a pdf.

```
Dictionary<string, string> GenCalculadora = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    GenCalculadora.Add("@FechaCalculo@", FechaCalculo);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@NombreCliente@}", NombreCliente);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@Posicion@}", Posicion);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@Vencimiento@}", Vencimiento);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@FechaCompra@}", FechaCompra);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@Fix@}", Fix);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@PrimaContraroAserca@}", PrimaContraroAserca);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@PrimaContraroAsercaT@}", PrimaContraroAsercaT);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@PrimaContratoCorreduria@}", PrimaContratoCorreduria);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@NumeroContratos@}", NumeroContratos);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@Incentivo@}", Incentivo);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@ComicionesContratoAserca@}", ComicionesContratoAserca);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@ComicionesContratoCorreduria@}", ComicionesContratoCorreduria);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@IncentivoPrima@}", IncentivoPrima);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@IncentivoComiciones@}", IncentivoComiciones);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@IncentivoTotal@}", IncentivoTotal);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@IncentivoDepositado@}", IncentivoDepositado);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@NombreRevisado@}", NombreRevisado);
                    GenCalculadora.Add("{@NombreElaborado@}", NombreElaborado);


// Creamos el PDF de una plantilla exitente en una ruta.
                    HtmlToPdf PlantillaHTM = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();      
                    PlantillaHTM.RenderUrlAsPdf(@"C:\Amoxcalli\FND_PROYECTO\SICOP\SistemaCoberturas\SICOP\plantillas/IncentivoASER.htm").SaveAs(@"C:\Amoxcalli\SIPRO_CalculaIncentivo.Pdf");
                    PlantillaHTM.PrintOptions.CssMediaType = PdfPrintOptions.PdfCssMediaType.Print;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el propósito de `GenCalculadora`? - no veo que lo esté usando en la instancia de HtmlToPdf llamada `PlantillaHTM`... Si este es un componente de un tercero, consulte la documentación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias aplicar el `Replace()` sobre el contenido del html, algo como esto

```
string htmlOrigen = @"C:\..\plantillas/IncentivoASER.htm";
string htmlDestino = @"C:\..\plantillas/IncentivoASER_Merged.htm";
string htmlContent = File.ReadAllText(htmlOrigen);

foreach(var item in GenCalculadora)
{
   htmlContent = htmlContent.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
}

File.WriteAllText(htmlDestino, htmlContent);

HtmlToPdf PlantillaHTM = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();      
var render = PlantillaHTM.RenderUrlAsPdf(htmlDestino);
render.SaveAs(@"C:\Amoxcalli\SIPRO_CalculaIncentivo.Pdf");
```

La idea es generar un html nuevo cuando se combina con los datos y ese enviarlo al pdf, asi te quedas siempre con un template que reutilizar

Comment: Gracias, tenía la certeza de que debía usar Foreach, pero no entendía como usarlo. Tengo una ultima pregunta; Algunos textos me salen de esta forma Cï¿½LCULO, Nï¿½mero y unos parámetros que se imprimen en variables así: ï¿½6546,0000ï¿½ ¿ ¿Como puedo normalizar el texto?

Comment: puede ser por el encoding aplicado al archivo, podrias ver de usar  `File.ReadAllText(htmlOrigen, Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: ¿Si  hubieran imágenes dentro la plantilla se usa algo parecido a los ejemplos de la  documentación?: var ImageFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\project\assets").Where(f => f.EndsWith(".jpg") || f.EndsWith(".jpeg"));

Comment: si hay imagenes deberias ponerlas como base64 y se trabaja como string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: Con esto doy por resuelta la pregunta. Por el apoyo y atención gracias :D